# Is there a way to customize the name for a wrapper function created by -Wl,--wrap?

Tags: c++, c, linker, ld

Using `-Wl,--wrap=foo` option one might change all unresolved `foo` references to `__wrap_foo`. Is there some way to achieve just that, but to customize the `__wrap_foo` name (preferably to something like `bar`, but even `__mywrap_foo` would suffice).
I'd like the solution that doesn't involve patching elfs if possible ;P

Comment: I don't think it is possible. Why would you need this?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I want to wrap a common stdlib function, like malloc, in my shared library and reduce/eliminate the likelihood that some other user of said lib tries to do the same (for their code that just links with my lib) and the wrapped functions collide.

Comment: "objcopy" can rename symbols, but granted, this might be what you call "patching ELF". -- Rename `malloc()` in your sources.